Having to replace inline well filter weekly
New well drilled 7 months ago and I'm having to change my inline filter every week because it's full of sand. What's the problem?

You have sandy soil?

The problem is your well is too shallow.
If you choose to not drill it deeper you may be successful with a series of filters. The spin down type of filters are self cleaning, in that you just open the valve at the bottom to clean the screens. There are "sand separator" filters made specifically for the issue you have. Start with a 40 mesh. Then progress to a final of 100 or 140.The mesh size is very important and need to progress from coarse to finer.
There are automatic flush valves that can be added and programed to flush the filters at a regular interval, so they are getting cleaned without you being there. Of course you will need an electric source and a drain for the flushed water. ( the ground could be ok, depending on the site.) A manifold can be built so one flush valve can work for all the filters.
The filters and products I added links for are made in the USA and sold world wide, so they are available in your location wherever you live.  You need only find a distributor or google the company and call them, they are very helpful. The mesh screens are available separately and very easy to change, if needed, without needing special tools or sealants.

You're using the wrong type of filter if the issue is sand, and you have to change it.
Look into a "spin-down filter with reservoir" where the sand is flung out by vortex action, collected in the bottom of the filter, and flushed by opening a valve at the bottom, which takes mere seconds. I use one of these with a 200 mesh screen element to remove manganese (mostly) particles from my well - it works nicely for that.
Put that in front of the (presumably) cartridge-type filter you must be using now.
Alternatively, use a sand filter (not a joke, literally a filter that uses sand as the filtering medium) and occasionally remove the excess, though the backwash cycle that cleans them may do that for you automatically. They are, however, an order or two of magnitude more expensive than the vortex type filters, and use a lot more space. They also filter more completely, so potentially worth being aware of, depending on your total filtering needs.
